# Should the [arithmetic] tag be removed from [math] synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I just noticed that [arithmetic](/questions/tagged/arithmetic) is a synonym of [math](/questions/tagged/math)([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/math/synonyms)).

IMO this is wrong because *arithmetic* is just a branch of mathematics, and in programming usually is used in contexts with a rather narrow scope. In fact, when a user tags a question with [arithmetic](/questions/tagged/arithmetic) probably he means to convey rather specific information, which the [math](/questions/tagged/math) doesn't provide.

Should the [arithmetic](/questions/tagged/arithmetic) tag be considered for removal from the synonyms of [math](/questions/tagged/math) then?

Comment: I can't remember the last time I wrote a program that didn't include maths